# How to send an array of strings in JSON to create multiple objects in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, paperclip

I want to assign to attachments to my document by sending two BASE64 strings in JSON like below.

```
curl -X POST \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-d '{"document":{"image_data":["some_base64_string_1", "some_base64_string_2"], "note":"Some note"}}' \
http://myap.dev/api/v1/documents.json

class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :image_data

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :attachments

  before_save :decode_image_data

  def decode_image_data
    if self.image_data.present?     
        # here I want to get image_data and create two attachments
        # image_data is right now nil
     end
  end
end
```

What should my JSON look like?

Answer (score 0):

Base64 is a red-herring (something that can confuse an argument) so let's put that aside for a minute.

JSON is capable of representing an array, so that's the place to start, because you want two of something. Pretending that we're doing what JavaScript and the browser would do is easy:

```
require 'json'

ary = ['content for box one', 'content for box two']
puts JSON[ary]
# >> ["content for box one","content for box two"]
```

At this point we have the same sort of base string that JavaScript would create for an array containing two ASCII strings. For this part of the test, it's inconsequential whether it's ASCII or binary.

Note that JSON left the content of the strings in the array alone. We can use the BASE64 encoding inside those strings and know that JSON will leave it alone:

```
puts JSON[ ary.map{ |s| Base64.encode64(s) } ]
# >> ["Y29udGVudCBmb3IgYm94IG9uZQ==\n","Y29udGVudCBmb3IgYm94IHR3bw==\n"]
```

That shows the sort of JSON string that you'd want to receive before reversing the process in Rails.

Assigning that to a variable (as if it was received from the browser) for further messin'-about:

```
incoming_json = JSON[ary.map{ |s| Base64.encode64(s) } ]
incoming_json
# => "[\"Y29udGVudCBmb3IgYm94IG9uZQ==\\n\",\"Y29udGVudCBmb3IgYm94IHR3bw==\\n\"]"
```

Pretend `incoming_json` is the JSON being received by Rails. Pass it to `JSON[]` to decode, and it will return that incoming string into an array of BASE64 encoded strings, which is what your incoming content would be. Decode those from BASE64 and you'll have an array of whatever was sent:

```
JSON[incoming_json].map{ |s| Base64.decode64(s) } 
# => ["content for box one", "content for box two"]
```

That's a round-trip encoding and decoding of two "binary" streams. It doesn't matter to BASE64 whether they're ASCII text or a stream of binary data, nor will JSON care, because it'll only be concerned with undoing the wrappers to create a Ruby array. What's inside those array elements will be of something else's concern, not JSON. That's why we pass the "unwrapped" array to `map` and let it play with the elements.